# Using AWS S3 version 2 signature with SHA256?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, sha256

I try to upload a file towards AWS S3 bucket through cURL.
With version 2 authentication and SHA1 it works well, but I'm not able to make it works with SHA256 (and version 2).

According to the online documentation normally we can do such a thing :

```
The hash-based protocol used to calculate the signature. This can be either HMAC-SHA1 or HMAC-SHA256 for Signature Version 2.
```

(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html)

Does anyone know if it's possible to use SHA256 with version 2 signature ?

Comment: Why version 2 and not version 4? Also why just use a SDK or the AWS CLI to upload a file to s3?

Comment: Indeed, I will use only sha1 with version 2 and sha256 with version 4, it will be simplier.